# Remove-NetFireWallRule Does Nothing?

Tags: powershell, firewall, windows-firewall, remove-netfirewallrule

I'm running this Powershell command to remove a Firewall rule:

`Remove-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'PPGooey (In) [7e3458172fa1a7e5b36fa09552dee4f9]'`

and it doesn't cough up any error, nor does it actually remove the rule. See screencast:

[image]

- In it, it shows the rule in the list
- The command is run
- The firewall list refreshed, and the rule still existing.

I also tried using `invoke-expression` as a test, though it's [recommended to avoid that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/avoid-using-invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.3):

`Invoke-Expression "Remove-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'PPGooey (In) [7e3458172fa1a7e5b36fa09552dee4f9]'"`

But no difference.

Any ideas why this won't remove the rule?

Comment: Have you tried running it as administrator?

Comment: @Paolo Yep. It is running as admin in that screencast. When not running that command as Admin it returns an error saying you don't have the right perms.